# How to send the Message to teams using Bot Framework?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have created one Chatbot using MS Bot Framework. Also added that in My Teams App. But not able to send messages to the users who not installed that app in there Teams. I just wanted to check if there is any provision to send the message to the users who not installed the Bot to there Teams App.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to send proactive messages to users who have not installed and interacted with your bot. Your bot has no way of knowing who those users are. If a user wants to communicate with the bot, they must install the app.

Comment: This is not true. The app must be installed, but you can send a message first by using graph to query the user's teams and channels, which allows you to find the conversation ID. I sent proactive messages to my employees before they have ever logged in. Secondly, the OP asked if there is a way to message users, but he did not specify through the bot itself. Sending a message to a user who has not installed the app is possible through graph.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to this. I ran into a similar issue where I had a Teams app that uses a notification style bot to send one-way notifications to users. The only way I was able to communicate to them was by getting the user context via an app install event. When an install event is captured, I save that users' context into a SQL database table in the event of the bot being restarted (then reload on start).

You can use the Graph API to install the bot automatically (see [Proactive installation of apps using Graph API to send messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=dotnet)) or install it via a MS Teams app setup policies (see [Install apps](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-faqplus/issues/24)).

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT There is no way to send proactive messages to users who have not installed and interacted with the bot then how this answer is helpful?